# Javascript store session value even after click back button

Tags: javascript

I need to know how I can show the input data of a form after a user presses the back button.

Here is the working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u75vzjtm/9/)

I created a simple asp page.

If I click next after entering some input value, it will go to next page, and again I click back, it doesn't show entered input values.

```
$("#form").submit(function() {
    var inputs=$('.input');
    for(i=0;i<inputs.length;i++)validateEmail(inputs[i]);
    if($('.invalid').length!==0)return false;
});
```

I need to show those values. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Note: In my jsfiddle didn't include next page action.

Comment: You can store the data in cookies.

Comment: You could use [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie), [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), and [more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)... Learning is journey but at least there are guides. :-)

Comment: Fastest way is using jquery plugin - https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several methods, althought I'm not a big fan of cookies because they are not so smart to manage.

You can either use:

- The `localStorage` API, if you want your values being saved until the user clears the cache, like this:

  ```
  var myValues = [];
  for(i=0;i<inputs.length;i++) {
      validateEmail(inputs[i]);
      myValues.push(inputs[i].value);
  }

  // Save them fot later use
  localStorage.myValues = JSON.stringify(myValues);

  // After clicking the button you can retrieve them back
  var oldValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.myValues);
  ```
- The `sessionStorage` API, which lives for the current session of the browser (i.e. when the user closes the browser it gets deleted):

  ```
  var myValues = [];
  for(i=0;i<inputs.length;i++) {
      validateEmail(inputs[i]);
      myValues.push(inputs[i].value);
  }

  // Save them fot later use
  sessionStorage.myValues = JSON.stringify(myValues);

  // After clicking the button you can retrieve them back
  var oldValues = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.myValues);
  ```

**NOTE:** I'm using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) because both storage objects (local and session) can only store data in string format.

Comment: @saina you can copy the first part (from `var newValues` to  `JSON.stringify`...) and put it in your code instead of your `for` loop. Then you can use the `var oldValues = JSON.parse(...)` part in the next page after submitting the values.

Comment: @saina edit your question and add the new code you are using (even the code on the next page)

Comment: @saina ok then just add `localStorage.myValues = JSON.strungify(myValues);` and you are ok. After this, in the next page you will just add the line `var oldValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.myValues);`, and then you will be able to use the `oldValues` variable to access the previously selected values.

Comment: @saina also you forgot to add the closing bracket `}` at the end of the `for` loop.

Comment: @saina you put the retrieve part in the same page, which is wrong. You have to use `var oldValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.myValues)` in the **next** page!

Comment: @saina for the fourth and last time: **include the last line to retrieve the values in your second page** (localhost/alertid/invitation_enroll5.asp?action=1...), at the beginning of your code.